# SDKs problem i can't upload my game in the web hosting

Tags: facebook-instant-games

hi bros can some one help me please when i was uploading the game this problem appears Games must reference one of our supported SDKs via our CDN.
i really need to understand why that happens so if u can help me as soon as possible i'll be grateful thanks

```js
     FB.init({appId: '1039135876270670', 
        status: true, // Check login status
        cookie: true, // Enables cookies so server can access the session
        xfbml: true // Parse XFBML});
        
          var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC,chD, correct = 0;
    var questions = [
        [ "What is 10 + 4?", "12", "14", "16","20", "B" ],
     [ "What is 20 - 9?", "7", "13", "11", "5","C" ],
     [ "What is 7 x 3?", "21", "24", "25", "27","A" ],
     [ "What is 8 / 2?", "10", "2", "4", "6","C" ]
    ];
    function _(x){
     return document.getElementById(x);
    }
    function renderQuestion(){
     test = _("test");
     if(pos >= questions.length){
      test.innerHTML = "<h2>Result<br> "+correct+" of "+questions.length+"</h2>";
      _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
      pos = 0;
      correct = 0;
      return false;
     }
     _("test_status").innerHTML = "Question "+(pos+1)+" of "+questions.length;
     question = questions[pos][0];
     chA = questions[pos][1];
     chB = questions[pos][2];
     chC = questions[pos][3];
        chD = questions[pos][4];
     test.innerHTML = "<div class='q'>"+question+"</div>";
     test.innerHTML += "<label><input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'class='rad' ><span>"+chA+"</span></label>";
     test.innerHTML += "<label><input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'class='rad' ><span>"+chB+"</span></label>";
     test.innerHTML += "<label><input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'class='rad' ><span>"+chC+"</span></label>";
        test.innerHTML += "<label><input type='radio' name='choices' value='D'class='rad' ><span>"+chD+"</span></label>";
     test.innerHTML += "<button class='btn' onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
    }
    function checkAnswer(){
     choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
     for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
      if(choices[i].checked){
       choice = choices[i].value;
      }
     }
     if(choice == questions[pos][5]){
      correct++;
     }
        else
        {
            correct--;
        }
     pos++;
     renderQuestion();
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
```

```html
        <pre>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <h2 id="test_status"></h2>
    <div id="test"></div>
    </pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the Facebook Connect SDK. Instant Games don't support the Facebook Connect SDK, they only work with the Facebook Instant Games SDK. The Instant Games SDK doesn't support regular Facebook Login, as they only run within Facebook.

You'd be best positioned reading the Getting Started guide here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/getting-started